# Function within Function in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have submit function on a button. Upon clicking "submit" a dialog box pops and asks for confirmation and after clicking "ok" the form is submitted.

Now I want to add another function in which upon clicking "ok" the form should be submitted & background color of page should also change. The code I wrote is given below. but now even the form is not submitting nor background color is changing. Help needed!

```
function myfunction(e) {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure to proceed with this role?')) {
            changecolor(e); 
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function changecolor(e) { 
        e.target.classList.add('custom_back')
    }

.custom_back{
backgroundcolor: #0065bd; }
```

Comment: Change `backgroundcolor` to `background-color`

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` will stop submit procedure

Comment: The background change is because of the CSS typo @Akshay pointed out. For the "not submitting" part, you probably want to remove the `return false` since it doesn't make any sense, and depending on how you hook `myFunction` up to the submit event, the `return false` may cancel submission. (I explain where `return false` does and doesn't prevent the default action in my blog post [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html).)

Comment: @Akshay it still wont work :(

Comment: Which part? @KamranShakeel the background or the form submit?

Comment: @Akshay the background part

Comment: If the color doesn't change after you decline the prompt, then inspect the button and see if the class has been added to it.

Comment: it would be helpful if you give us the code in JSFiddle

Comment: @ArslanHaider I would but the code has bindings with other pages so it wont work in other environment. any other solution?

Comment: @Akshay the target is upon Accepting the prompt the color should be changed

Comment: @KamranShakeel In that case you should remove the `!`

Comment: @Akshay keeping ! works fine the form is submitting after OK in dialog box and does not submit upon clicking cancel. removing ! results vice versa.

Comment: @Akshay but the background still remains same

Comment: @KamranShakeel Try inspecting the button and see if the class gets added after you accept the confirmation

Answer (score -1):

code is fine function within a function will always work you just need to  remove not condition in if.

here is working code

```js
function myfunction(e) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure to proceed with this role?')) {
            changecolor(e); 
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function changecolor(e) { 
        e.target.classList.add('custom_back');
    }
```

```css
.custom_back{
background:green;
color:white
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick=myfunction(event) value="Submit"/>
```